# Fetch data from Subquery consisting 2 tables in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I am having a query which has 2 tables. I need to use it as query annotation in repository class to fetch data from database

this is how my query looks something like this

```
select * from TABLE1 where COL1 = (select COL2 from TABLE2 where COL3 = 'data') or COL1 = 'data'
```

Now as it has 2 tables I need to make some Entity which can have multiple tables

I know how to make an Entity for 1 table->

```
@Entity

@Table(name = 'TABLE1')
public class DisplayEntity implements Serializable {


@Column(name = 'COL1')
private String someVariable

//getters and setters
}
```

and repository class will look like ->

```
@Repository

public DisplayDataRepository extends CrudRepository<DisplayEntity,Long>
{
@Query(select * from TABLE1)
List<DisplayEntity> displayDatainTable();
```

This will work if I have single table in query but it is not working when I am having 2 tables as shown above in the above query

Can anyone please help me how we can have a query implemented in repository class having 2 tables and how should my Entity class looks like

Thank you

Comment: what is error/issue you are facing

Comment: Hi when i try to run I am getting 'unknown column name COL1' if i run for the above complex query. but if i just run this query-> select * from TABLE1 I get no error. I think i need to map both tables to entity somehow.Can you please help me thanks

Comment: Did you try to giving alias to table and using columns with alias, because I used multiple tables reference without any isssues

Comment: Sorry but what is alias?

Comment: select t1.* from TABLE1 t1
where t1.COL1 = (select t2.COL2 from TABLE2 t2 where t2.COL3 = 'data') or t1.COL1 = 'data'

Comment: Ohh ok and how should my entity class look like? I mean should it have columns from both the tables?

Comment: Can you share your problem in GitHub so that i can look and fix it

Comment: Sorry but I can't upload the project on github :(   the project is exactly same as above my question is in entity we provide column annotation so which columns should I provide there like I have two tables if I provide column name of one table and run query then it throws error like unknown column name coz column name is actually not there in my entity class. I mean should I give column names of both tables in one entity class? If yes then how can I have both tables in table annotation